# Need a Mental Challenge

Tags: pathfinder-1e, encounter-design

I am running a custom campaign and I have run into an issue. The group got to a quest where the ruler of the country is dying of old age and a has no heir. So someone needs to prove themselves to both the Orcs and the Elves. They took on the Orc physical challenge with no problem, but I have no idea what mental challenge to throw at them when they reach the Elves.

The Orc challenge was more or less straight forward. They got to the main camp of the orcs and had to challenge the Orc Warlord to a physical fight. The only thing that wasn't quite what it seemed was the there was a huge warrior orc in the middle of the tent training, the Warlord was sitting on the ground in the back watching. After a while they figured out who the Warlord was. I am hoping for a mental challenge similar to this, seeming straight forward, with a slight twist.

Comment: Written test on economics, statescraft, court etiquette, history and culture of neighboring countries, and artesian woodworking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if this is a test of their ability as a ruler, I would suggest something like Chess or something else that has mental strategy to it. To make it interesting, make it so the pieces are people and not played on a regular board. They would act out the moves to show that they understood strategy.

The other option is for the elves to give them a mental task to choose between two hard choices, like the classic, "You can only save one person, who will it be"? Make sure there will be a legitimate tough choice for the PC's as they will be easily detached from the decision if they do not care about the NPCs involved. This test could be more of a test to see if they will make tough decisions, not necessarily what is the right answer.

As you can see there is more than one way to approach this.

Comment: I had not thought of the "Tough Choice" option.